# how to use multiple view engine like ejs and jsx in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using ejs and jsx both file as template in node.js project but I am unable to find any solution and get error like this:

my code where both view engine included given under:

```
//view engine setup
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
var options = { beautify: true };
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine(options));

var engines = require('consolidate');

app.engine('ejs', engines.ejs);
```

on execution i am getting error "Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory"
while i have created both jsx file and ejs file in view directory but not rendering.Any one can give me solution?

Comment: Do you have a `login.ejs` file in your `views` directory?

Comment: yes I have login.ejs file in view directory .is there any issue ?

Comment: Can I see the directory structure?

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @ArunKumar My Directory structure like this: node-shopping\myapp , node-shopping\myapp\app\controllers\home.js , node-shopping\myapp\app\models\home.js , node-shopping\myapp\app\views\login.ejs , node-shopping\myapp\app\views\home.ejs , node-shopping\myapp\app\views\category.jsx , node-shopping\myapp\config , node-shopping\myapp\public , node-shopping\myapp\package.json , node-shopping\myapp\app.js , above my directory structure.